# Travis Client - Login with BitBucket account

Tags: kubernetes, bitbucket, travis-ci

I'm trying to encrypt a service account file for Google Cloud and transfer over BitBucket to eventually deploy to GCP Kubernetes. I'm using the travis command line to do this, but whenever I try to log in via the command line it assumes I have a GitHub account associated with Travis CI not BitBucket.

```
travis encrypt-file service.json -r USERNAME/REPO
```

When I run this, Travis assumes I have trying to auth a GitHub account and asks me to login. It tries to validate my username and password against GitHub not BitBucket.

```
We need your GitHub login to identify you.
```

Is there an alternative command line command that lets me force a BitBucket login? Or a workaround for allowing me to encrypt the file and include in my .travis.yml build file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-t TRAVIS_TOKEN` instead of authentication via `login` command (login command assumes that you want to login via GitHub)

Your encrypt command will look like this:
`travis encrypt-file --pro --repo USER/REPO -t TRAVIS_TOKEN file --add`

Steps to get user token:

1. Login into Travis (via BitBucket)
2. Click your user icon (top right corner) and select `Settings`
3. This will show you your `Repositories` with option to show `Settings` or `Plan`.
4. Select `Settings`
5. Click `Copy token` from API authentication

Or just click this link [Travis CI preferences](https://travis-ci.com/account/preferences) and `Copy Token`.